# Return double value of each element in array

Tags: arrays, swift

My function needs to return a new array with each value doubled.

For example:

[1, 2, 3] --> [2, 4, 6]

I wrote this code, but it's not good:

```swift
func maps(a : Array<Int>) -> Array<Int> {
    var arrSize = a.count
    var arr = Array<Int>()
    var i = 0
    while arrSize > 0{
      arr += a[i] * 2
      i += 1
      arrSize -= 1
    }
  return arr
}
```

Comment: Define “not good”. What actual issue are you having with your code?

Comment: `arr += CollectionOfOne(a[i] * 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that "it's not good" is extremely unhelpful. You need to explain what is wrong with your code and how it fails to meet your needs. For more complex questions, it's going to be hard for your readers to know what is wrong with the code unless you tell us.

Taking pity on you because you're new:

This line:

```
arr += a[i] * 2
```

is not legal. You can't use the `+=` operator to append an item to an array.

---

### EDIT:

As pointed out in the comments, it **is** legal to append one array to another with +=, so you *could* have written `arr += [a[i] * 2]`, but WHY?

---

Replace it with:

```
arr.append( a[i] * 2)
```

And your code will work.

Not that you can do this with a single line:

```
func doubleArray(_ array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
  array.map { $0 * 2 }
}
```

---

### EDIT:

(And given that using map collapses this code down to a single line, why even create a function? Just use .map { $0 * 2 } any place you want to multiply the values in an array by 2.)

---

Comment: You don't need `return` for a one-line function

Comment: You can append to the array with `+=` if the value is an array: `arr += [a[i] * 2]`

Comment: @vacawama better to use [`CollectionOfOne`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collectionofone) `arr += CollectionOfOne(a[i] * 2)`

Comment: @LeoDabus, I would think that a good compiler should be able to optimize that to the same result.

Comment: @vacawama probably but I still prefer to use `CollectionOfOne` considering that it exists solely for this purpose

Comment: Why type 2 characters when you can type 17, lol.